# Прозрачность по краям фона

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как реализовать прозрачность по краям блока? Похожую на прозрачность по бокам карты на этом скриншоте..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно сделать градиентную маску (например радиальную)

```css
div, img { 
  position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:250px; height:250px; 
 }
 
img {
      -webkit-mask-image:-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
      mask-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 90%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sit amet porttitor massa. Morbi eget tortor congue, aliquet odio a, viverra metus. Ut cursus enim eu felis sollicitudin, vitae eleifend urna lobortis. Mauris elementum erat non facilisis cursus. Fusce sit amet lacus dictum, porta libero sed, euismod tellus. Aenean erat augue, sodales sed gravida ac, imperdiet ac augue. Ut condimentum dictum mauris. Donec tincidunt enim a massa molestie, vel volutpat massa dictum. Donec semper odio vitae adipiscing lacinia.</div>
    
<img src='https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000528/109/i/600/depositphotos_1094381-stock-photo-beautiful-beach-and-sea.jpg' />
```

Можно сделать наложение непрозрачного изображения меньшего размера на полупрозрачное большего размера, вместо `img` использовать `div` с соответствующим задним фоном

Comment: Пока отвечал на enSO, забыл, что не нажал "отправить ответ" здесь :) Практически один в один.

Answer (score 1):

Можно провернуть нечто подобное с помощью box-shadow:

```css
.example {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-image: url(pic.jpg);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="example"></div>
```

Comment: Немного не то получается, тут затемнение идёт, а нужна прозрачность( Тоже вначале так пробовал. Но за совет все равно спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Вариант, если фон одного цвета

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}

.minimap {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  position: relative;
}

.minimap::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 12px #444 inset;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.minimap img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="minimap">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/TRJSwhF.png">
</div>
```

---

Если использовать так называемый `alpha` слой при помощи [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask)

```css
body {
  background: url('//i.imgur.com/6U5tB7F.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.minimap {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  --blur: 15px;
  --spread: 10px;
  /* не изменять */
  --grad: transparent calc(var(--spread)), 
      #fff calc(var(--spread) + var(--blur)), 
      #fff calc(100% - (var(--spread) + var(--blur))), 
      transparent calc(100% - var(--spread));
  /* не изменять */
  mask-image: 
    linear-gradient(to right, var(--grad)),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--grad));
  mask-composite: intersect;
}

.minimap img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="minimap">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/TRJSwhF.png">
</div>
```